# Determining How To Authorize with NodeJS/Mongoose

Tags: node.js, express, authentication, mongoose, passport.js

I am working on a NodeJS/express application using passportJS for sign in/sign up. I have defined a user model for all users, but want only certain users within my administration to have access to editing certain models. I was thinking of adding a boolean field, like isAdmin to determine this, but I don't know how I would verify admin users. To be specific, how would I determine when I need to generate a token for the admin user? How do I differentiate users in my administrations from ordinary users? I was thinking of having a separate locally hosted website that connects to the same database that I could use to manage models only from my computer. Would that work?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many option available. i can explain you some of them.

1) As you said you can define boolean field as is Admin true of false.

-> if you are using this option and you are using passport. You must get user in your request object.Before hitting api or particular endpoint you can set middleware to verify that requested user is admin or user.
file

Filename : ../services/auth.service.js

```
            exports.isAdmin = async (req, res, next) => {
                        // req.user is object that you will get after successfull login. change accordingly
                        // Or you can check from db also. Get object logged in user from db by their email id.
                        // And check condition
                        // Check Role if admin or not
                        if(req.user.isAdmin) {
                            next(); // If verify it will redirect to next process
                        } else {
                            return res.status(401).json({
                                Error: true,
                                message: 'You are not authorized to perform this action.',
                            })              
                        }

            };
```

You can use this function as middleware.

```
            const auth = require('../services/auth.service.js')

            router.get('/*', auth.isAdmin, (req, res) => {
                res.status(200).json({ message: "Hello from Admin side."})
            });
```

Visit : https://github.com/mihir-kanzariya/Nodejs-CRUD

Comment: Thank you for your answer! But, I am still confused as to how I determine if the user is an administrator or not in order to be able to set the isAdmin boolean to True or False.